# Change Background Image of Div When Modal Popup Window Opens

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, encoding, simplemodal

I'm trying to dynamically change the background image of a div inside of a modal popup window.  I first tried it with simplemodal  and now I am trying it with the jqueryui dialog box.  I can't get it to work on either one.  Here is my code so far:

```
//Jquery Dialog Attempt:  
//I have also tried it in the open event
        $(".Previous tr td img:not(.Help)").live("click", function(){
            var mediumImage = $(this).parent().find("img.mediumImage");
            var smallImageDiv = $("div#modal table tr td div#smallerImage");
            var backgroundImageString = "url(\"" + mediumImage.attr("src").toString() + "\")";
            smallImageDiv.css('backgroundImage', backgroundImageString);
            $("div#modal").dialog({
                height:300,
                modal:true,
                close: function(){
                    $(this).dialog('destroy');
                }
            });
        });

//SimpleModal attempt
$(".Previous tr td img:not(.Help)").live("click", function(){
    var mediumImage = $(this).parent().find("img.mediumImage");
    var smallImageDiv = $("div#modal table tr td div#smallerImage");
    $("#modal").modal({
        onOpen: function(){
            var backgroundImageString = "url(\"" + mediumImage.attr("src").toString() + "\")";
            smallImageDiv.css('backgroundImage', backgroundImageString);
        },
        onShow: function(){
            $("html").css("overflow", "hidden");
        },
        onClose: function(){
            $("html").css("overflow", "auto");
            $(".Previous tr td img").live("click", function(){});
            $.modal.close();
        }
    });
});
```

EDIT: Based On Suggestion From ghoppe
Apparently I'm having a strange encoding problem when setting the background image property.

Test:

```
//The path to the image is: Thumbnails\\2010\1\28\THUMBNAIL\0123456-0123a1of3_med.JPG
var backgroundImageString = "url(" + mediumImage.attr("src").toString() + ")";
smallImageDiv.css('background-image', backgroundImageString);
alert(backgroundImageString.toString()); //This is correct
alert(smallImageDiv.css('background-image').toString()); //Lots of escaped characters
```

Solution:
I needed to escape my image path.

```
var backgroundImageString = "url(" + escape(mediumImage.attr("src")) + ")";
```

Comment: Hah! After thinking about dropping the .toString() thing, I was just going to suggest that. Grats. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`smallImageDiv.css('backgroundImage', backgroundImageString);`
should be

```
smallImageDiv.css('background-image', backgroundImageString);
```

Comment: Still doesn't appear in the div, Thanks for the suggestion though!

Comment: Sorry I now realize as per http://api.jquery.com/css/, jquery understands the DOM formatting of multiple-word properties, so this wasn't your issue. Have you checked to see if the image comes up 404?

Comment: Have you tried dropping the `.toString()` altogether? .attr() will already contain a string.